# Can not connect to rpc server bitcoind 0.16

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I have 2 server v0.18 and 0.16. They're nearly same config but I can't connect to v0.16 server via RPC though using command on it is still well eg `bitcoin-cli -info`. 
I have searched few configs and none of them are useful for my case, please help me check this config, thanks so much.
v0.16 can not connect:

```
datadir=/data/bitcoind
debuglogfile=/var/log/bitcoin_testnet.log
dbcache=1000
txindex=1
server=1
rpcuser=...
rpcpassword=...
rpcport=18888
port=18887
daemon=1
testnet=1
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0

[test]
rpcbind=0.0.0.0

walletnotify=/data/bitcoind/bitcoind_walletnotify.sh %s
blocknotify=/data/bitcoind/bitcoind_blocknotify.sh %s
```

I have tried to drop `rpcbind=0.0.0.0` and `port` but it's not worked. Example on my other server v0.18 can connect via RPC well:

```
server=1
testnet=1
txindex=1
dbcache=2048

rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0    
rpcuser=...
rpcpassword=...

datadir=/data/blockchain/bitcoin/
debuglogfile=/var/log/bitcoin.log

# Limit 25 transactions
#limitdescendantcount=300
#limitancestorcount=300

[test]
rpcport=18332
rpcbind=0.0.0.0

#[regtest]
# Notify when receiving coins
walletnotify=/data/blockchain/bitcoin/bitcoin_walletnotify.sh %s
blocknotify=/data/blockchain/bitcoin/bitcoin_blocknotify.sh %s
```

Comment: If you run the version 0.16 with the default configuration work? I think could be the port of the node with the version 0.16 is locked

Comment: I try to switch other port but on log is always failed: `2019-08-16 09:22:23 Binding RPC on address :: port 18991 failed.`, same to default `bitcoind - daemon`.

Comment: try to run the bitcoind -rpcport=18888 -rpcuser=... -rpcpassword=.. if worked the problem is the link to bitcoin.cong

Comment: `bitcoind -daemon -debug=rpc -debug=mempool -rpcuser=btcrpc -rpcpassword=... -rpcport=18991 -rpcbind=0.0.0.0 -rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0 -testnet -server -debuglogfile=/var/log/bitcoin_testnet.log`, no `binding port failed` anymore but I still can not connect. :-(

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo, detail there:
https://pastebin.com/smdNiq5K

Comment: In your logs doesn't exist any error, right? the bitcoind running

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97482/discussion-between-mmo2112-and-vincenzopalazzo).